# Cross-Site Collection query/cache

Tags: development

i wonder of this is technically possible.

We have 17000 sites.
Some people might have workflows in some of these sites with tasks assigned to them.

Lets say a normal user can have up to 20 workflows with tasks associated to him self in some of those 17000 site collections.

I want to create maybe a webpart or an application page that shows the task where you need to do something.

This could be really expensive in terms of resources due to the number of sites we have.
What would be the best approach, and can the results be cached? so that it doesnt execute the query if they press F5 each time, maybe refresh every 1hour or so.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use search.  You can create a scope specifically for tasks and maybe create additional managed properties if needed.  I use this to present a count of outstanding tasks on an intranet homepage for the current user - they can then click on the count to get the detail including links to each task.

Comment: with the new content search web part?

Comment: The example I give above is actually in 2010 with a call to the search web service but yes, the CSWP would be fine.